# Count specific column in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table *contact* with three columns e.g. *name*, *surname* and *age*.
I would like to count the number of entries from the specific column *surname*.
How looks the select statement in DB2 to achieve this?

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT COUNT()`.

Comment: Please add a sample table with data to your question.  There are a few interpretations of what you are asking.

Comment: I can't it is forbidden. I told you the problem situation for example.

Comment: `it is forbidden` ... so you are forbidden from completely fabricating a 5-10 record table with sample data to get help with your problem?  Do you work for NSA or something?

Comment: no for a company, and I can't post the data, because we have policies.

Comment: @Gordon, Select Count(surname) from contact worked but the heading is 00001, how can I Change the heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the column name using `as` :

```
select count(surname) as surname_count
from contact c;
```

Comment: thank you, this is the right answer. Don't know why some people are angry to me?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to perform a

`select count(surname) 
from contact 
group by surname`

but you need to put some effort into the question and prove you have already researched a bit beforehand